# Adding a classname to a span generated using AJAX and PHP arrays

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, draggable

I cannot get my head around why this keeps breaking.

I have a number of words stored in an array:

```
$poolOne=array("sparkly","sporty","happy","confident","awesome","funny","awkward","mad","silly","dynamic",
    "handsome","merry","horrid","funky","loud","chirpy","posh","clever","pretty","athletic");
```

A call to this array chooses four random words and outputs them inside a `<span>`

```
<?php foreach (array_rand($poolOne, 4) as $key) {
    echo "<span>".$poolOne[$key]."</span>";
}?>
```

In order to generate a new random set of four words without refreshing the page, I've used a very simple AJAX call which reloads the section only and gives you a new set of four words.

You can see this in action here, the page loads with code in the div `wordbank` and then when the AJAX is run (`onClick` of the green button) it loads the same PHP again from a file called `wordbank.php`

http://francesca-designed.me/create-a-status/index.php

This is the standard AJAX call, nothing special:

```
function refreshWords()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("wordbank").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","wordbank.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

This all works fine, as you can see on the link above.

However the next step, I want to use jQuery UI to make the words drag and droppable. The first step of this is giving each of the `spans` with my words in a class of `draggable` so the jQuery can do it's thing. **But this is where I am running into problems**.

As soon as I add `class="draggable"` to the PHP call, the whole thing breaks.

Why would simply adding a classname to this call break it?

Here it is without

```
echo "<span>".$poolOne[$key]."</span>";
```

Here it is with

```
echo "<span class="draggable">".$poolOne[$key]."</span>";
```

**Add this classname** and the whole page goes kaboom. I get **Server Error 500**

Here s a version of the site I've duplicated, with just the draggable class added and nothing else. You can see that it doesn't work at all.

I can't understand why adding a simple classname is destroying my entire page?

Version which is broken: http://francesca-designed.me/create-a-status/index2.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape your quotes, or use different quotes:

```
echo '<span class="draggable">'.$poolOne[$key].'</span>';
```

Your original one was breaking because your quote after `class=` was ending your string.

Comment: It's worth mentioning to OP that quotes can also be escaped if the delimiter needs to be the same type of quote `"<span class=\"draggable\">"`

Comment: @Popnoodles, he does mention that _"You need to escape your quotes"_

Comment: An example of escaping quotes may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> echo "".$poolOne[$key]."";
>   You break your code by "

mask it like:

```
echo "<span class=\"draggable">\".$poolOne[$key]."</span>";
```

or use ' (single quote)

```
echo '<span class="draggable">".$poolOne[$key]."</span>';
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    My first thought is have you included the jquery-ui.js?

    check this out:
    http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

    You need to add id='draggable' and class='ui-widget-content' to your span/div.

    And to make it draggable, invoke draggable() method on the span/div:
    $(function() {
      $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    });
```